# json data not displaying in table layout in android

Tags: android, json

Hi in the below code I am displaying table layout for table format.But in my activity only displaying the heading.but values are not displaying.

In the below code data String also displaying the values

Can any one help me

**java**

```
public class General_patient_list extends Activity {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView label;
    String queryString;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.general_collection_report);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
        final String date1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("date1");
        final String date2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("date2");


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                queryString = "date1=" + date1 + "&date2="
                        + date2;
                data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("general_registration",queryString);
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Patients> patients = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(patients);                     
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public ArrayList<Patients> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<Patients> patients = new ArrayList<Patients>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Patients patient = new Patients();
                //patient.setSi(json_data.getInt("si"));
                patient.setRegno(json_data.getString("reg_no"));
               // patient.setPat_name(json_data.getString("pat_name"));
               patient.setSex(json_data.getString("sex"));
                patient.setReg_date(json_data.getString("reg_date"));
               patient.setAddress(json_data.getString("address"));
                patients.add(patient);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return patients;
    }

    void addHeader(){
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
       // label = new TextView(this);
        //label.setText("Si");
       // label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
       //         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //label.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
      //  LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
      //  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
      //          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      //  params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
       // Ll.addView(label,params);
       // tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView reg_no = new TextView(this);
        reg_no.setText("Reg_No");
        reg_no.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        reg_no.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        reg_no.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(reg_no,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
       TextView pat_name = new TextView(this);
        pat_name.setText("Patient Name");
        pat_name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        pat_name.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        pat_name.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(pat_name,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView sex = new TextView(this);
        sex.setText("Sex");
        sex.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        sex.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        sex.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(sex,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView reg_date = new TextView(this);
        reg_date.setText("Registration Date");
        reg_date.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        reg_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        reg_date.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(reg_date,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView address = new TextView(this);
        address.setText("Address");
        address.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        address.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        address.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(address,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

         // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Patients> patients) {

        addHeader();

        for (Iterator i = patients.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            Patients p = (Patients) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            //label = new TextView(this);
          //  label.setText(p.getSi());
           // label.setId(p.getSi());
           // label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           //         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           // label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          //  label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
          //  LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
          //  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        //            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //    params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        //    Ll.addView(label,params);
         //   tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            TextView reg_no = new TextView(this);
            reg_no.setText(p.getRegno());
            reg_no.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            reg_no.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            reg_no.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(reg_no,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
           TextView pat_name = new TextView(this);
            pat_name.setText(p.getPat_name());
            pat_name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            pat_name.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            pat_name.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(pat_name,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            TextView sex = new TextView(this);
            sex.setText(p.getSex());
            sex.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            sex.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            sex.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(sex,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            TextView reg_date = new TextView(this);
            reg_date.setText(p.getReg_date());
            reg_date.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            reg_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            reg_date.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(reg_date,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            TextView address = new TextView(this);
            address.setText(p.getAddress());
            address.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            address.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            address.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(address,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

             // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing for loop as below

```
for (int i=0; i<patients.size(); i++) {
    Patients p = patients.get(i);

}
```

also check if patients array is empty or not by debugging.